# What is the latest windows 7 release as on November 2018

Tags: sql-server, windows, server, version

- I could see that my windows 7 is (Version 6.1, build 7601, SP1)
- But    I am facing issues with installing SQL Server 2017, due to
  outdated OS.
- Thanks in advance

Comment: that is the minimum requirement for `SQL Server 2017`. Either you upgrade your OS or use a earlier version of `SQL Server`

Comment: So, if I am satisfying the minimum requirements for SQL Server, Why can't I be able to install, and to which version could I able to upgrade?? please help on the version

Comment: refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2017 [requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#TOP_Principal) at least Windows 8, so you can't install it on Windows 7 at all. Windows 7 is [out of mainstream support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet) for almost 4 years already, and Windows 8 is out of mainstream support for about an year. If your are asking for a desktop Windows version, you should be on Windows 10 to use it.